# Linear programming: SOS2 clarification

Tags: linear-programming

I am working on a project where I am using SOS2 in a linear program.

I am seeing some behaviour, with regards to these SOS2, that I did not expect.

I am not sure whether I use the SOS2 wrong or if that is the correct behaviour.

My question and what I would like clarification on, is two things:

1. Can an SOS2 have a situation, where only one element will be non-zero? Rather than always have two elements being non-zero.
2. If the above is indeed true, then if you have a SOS2 with only one element, then that would always be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Even better: there can be zero non-zero members. SOS2 says "at most two members are non-zero and these members are neighbors". The phrase "at most" should be taken literally.
2. No. A SOS2 set with a single member will have at most one non-zero value. So it can be zero. (Of course a SOS2 set with one member is somewhat silly).

Here I assume the bounds are zero and +infinity. With nonzero lower bounds the story becomes a little bit more complicated.

I believe solvers tend to document this correctly (I don't remember ever seeing this defined incorrectly).